# Change code and compile a C++ project, e.g. tesseract

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, makefile, tesseract

I downloaded the source of tesseract,

achieved to configure, make and install it on Ubuntu 14.04

I need to change some lines and try something.

But after editing the code how can i compile it?

As i remember i had achieved this a while ago with some line like below:

```
gcc -Lsomelibrary -I somethingelse
```

I need to know how to recompile with my code changes.

Comment: maybe you need to run `make` again?

Comment: is it enough? so simple? thanks

Comment: And `make install` if you're going to install it over the previous installation

Comment: Just `make` again, and then either `install` again or find the binary to execute from the command line.

Comment: take a look into the makefile, maybe `make clean`, `make` and `make install` did the job.

Comment: Actually, depending on the nature of your changes (theoretically you may change absolutely everything in the package) you may need to wipe out the previous installation and then run `make install`. But if your changes are small enough, then simple `make install` is enough.